# Haskell error using foldr

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and trying out some exercises

I dont understand whats the error generated and why it is generated

```
split = foldr 
        (\x y -> y:x)
        [[]]
```

the error on the interpretator is as below

```
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `y'
    In the expression: y : x
    In the first argument of `foldr', namely `(\ x y -> y : x)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us more details about he expected type of split? Because just reversing y with x does nothing, it gives you back the same list of list that was given as input, it is the same as foldr (:) [[]] .

Comment: like maybe for example splitting into even and odd numbers?

Answer (score 6):

Type of foldr is

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

so in split

```
split = foldr (\x y -> y:x) [[]]
```

`y` and `y:x` has to be of same type, which is not possible for any `x` and `y` as `y:x` will always be one step deeper in the list than `y`.

I think you wanted to do `x:y`?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the type of `foldr`: `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. This says that `foldr` expects a function that combines an element of the list with a value of the final result type, producing a new value of the result type.

For the first argument, you've given `foldr` the function `\x y -> y:x`, where `x` will be the list elements and `y` the result of the next step to the right; and the result of applying this lambda should have the same type as `y`.

But the type of `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`--that is, it appends a single element to the head of a list. In the expression `y:x`, you're taking something of the "result" type and using it as an element of a list used as the result.

Because of that, GHC attempts to infer that the result type `b` is the same as the type `[b]`, which is then of course the same as the type `[[b]]`, and `[[[b]]]`... and so on. Thus it complains about an "infinite type".

Comment: can u explain the last part?I dont quite catch. what does the '[[]]' refer to?

Comment: @edelweiss: Just like `[b]` is a list with elements of type `b`, `[[b]]` is a list with elements of type `[b]`. In other words, a list of lists. Likewise, `[[[b]]]` is a list of lists of lists, &c.

Comment: am i correct to say that '[[]]' refers to the type of output expected?

Comment: how do I actually achieve this type of outing in haskell?

Answer (score 1):

The posts before me answer your question, but after your comment i can see that you want a function that splits your list by a predicate.

You can use groupWith::Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]] from the module GHC.Exts and supply it with a function of type (a -> Bool) in your example:

```
groupWith even [1,2,3,4,5,6] yields [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

Also, something ugly but that achieves the type of "outing" you want is:

```
split::Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
split f ls = (ls \\ rl):rl:[]
    where rl = filter f ls
```

But this will always split the supplied list in just two lists because of the binary function you supply.

Comment: `Data.List.partition` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: That should be the way to go, and that would be also something that he could easily implement, but he was also interested that the output type be a list of lists and not a tuple.